# How to perform go back function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router-v4

I am using **react-router** v.4 and I would like to perform some go back function.

My current code looks as below:

```
<HashRouter>
       <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Main}/>
            <Route path='/secondview' component={SecondView}/>
            <Route path='/traineeships' render={()=>(<Traineeship rootState={this.state} setRootState={this.setState.bind(this)} />)}/>
            <Route path='/information-filter' render={()=>(<InformationFilter rootState={this.state} setRootState={this.setState.bind(this)} />)}/>
            <Route path='/find-work' render={()=>(<FindWork rootState={this.state} setRootState={this.setState.bind(this)} />)}/>
            <Route path='/information-job' render={()=>(<InformationJob rootState={this.state} setRootState={this.setState.bind(this)} />)}/>
            <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
       </Switch>
```

I tried several options like `this.props.history.go(-1)` on other components but I was getting undefined errors.

Anyone knows how to perform go back function in my case?

Comment: @VicJordan I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'goBack' of undefined when i am doing same as the answer on that duplicate quetsion!

Comment: are you using `withRouter` for your pages? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to get a better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `withRouter`, if you need to access history object:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class SecondView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.props.history.go(-1)} />
    )
  }
}

const SecondViewnWithRouter = withRouter(SecondView)
```

> withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the
>   wrapped component whenever it renders.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the the version of `react-router` (in this case 3.0) you could enable `BrowserHistory first`and do:

```
const BrowserHistory = require('react-router/lib/BrowserHistory').default;
```

and you could use it in JSX:

```
<button onClick={BrowserHistory.goBack}>Back</button>
```

And this code in your App file:

```
<Router history={BrowserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

Comment: I am getting Error: Cannot find module "react-router/lib/BrowserHistory"

Comment: @Mizlul I did not notice you are using v4 :)